# Is it possible to link to a file inside of a magnet link?

Tags: file-sharing, bittorrent, p2p, magnet-links

I would like to provide magnet links in my service, for large downloadable files. However, I would like to be able to tell the Torrent-download client only to grab a specific file within the torrent/magnet. Is this possible and how can it be done?

Comment: No, you can't do that.
More detail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create separate torrents for each set of files you want, then spawn magnet links for each.

As far as I have seen there are no switches you can include in magnet link that will define intra-torrent settings. Even if it could, there would be no guarantee the client would recognize and obey those commands.

Comment: +1 - Are you saying you would have a 'master' file just referencing the external files?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if he wants to distribute different sets of files, it is far simpler to just make multiple torrent files, and distribute as needed. You can even make all the torrent files build into the same folder structure. That way if someone needed every file, they would just download all the torrent files and save them in the same place.